# Extra space in responsive css using float:left;

Tags: css, responsive, space

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why this code can't work. I am trying to set up a personal website and before I put my content in place, I want to have all of the areas setup and have it be responsive. I want a 3x3 grid of boxes where I can display my work (div id = container), but every time I introduce the ninth div block specifically (p9), the arrangement breaks for seemingly no reason. Here's the code for the desktop layout:

```
body{
    background-color:#FFB51E;
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
    position:absolute;
}

 /* unvisited link */
a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: #2A56C4;
    color:#fff;
    padding:15px;
    border-radius:26px;
    }
/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: fff;
    }
/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    background-color:#FF581E;
    }
/* selected link */
a:active {
    color:#FF581E;
    background-color:fff;
    }

#header{
    width:80%;
    height:160px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    display:block;

}

.left{
    color:#fff;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    font-size:36px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:310px;
    display:block;
}

.right{
    text-align:right;
    width:300px;
    float:right;
    padding-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    font-size:24px;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    z-index:2;
}

.works{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    left:30%;
    font-size:25px;
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.about{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    right:30%;
    font-size:25px;
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.border{
    background-color:none;
    width:100%;
    height:85px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #000;
    float:none;
    position:relative;
}
/*body stuff*/
    #container{
    position:static;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:0px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    width:80%;
    height:550px;
}

    .p1{
        background-color: aliceblue;
        color:000;
        font-size:12px;
        width:230px;
        z-index: 1;
        float:left;
        margin: 0px;
        padding:0px;

    }

    .p2{
        background-color: red;
        width:230px;
        z-index: 1;
        float:left;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .p3{
        background-color: blue;
        width:230px;
        z-index: 1;
        float:left;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }

    .p4{
        background-color: purple;
        width:230px;
        z-index: 1;
        float:left;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding:0px;

    }

    .p5{
        background-color: green;
        width:230px;
        z-index: 1;
        float:left;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .p6{
        background-color: brown;
        width:230px;
        z-index: 1;
        float:left;
        padding:0px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .p7{
        background-color: purple;
        width:230px;
        z-index: 1;
        float:left;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding:0px;

    }

    .p8{
        background-color: green;
        width:230px;
        z-index: 1;
        float:left;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .p9{
        background-color: green;
        width:230px;
        z-index: 1;
        float:left;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding:0px;
    }
```

I'm about five minutes from drop kicking my laptop out the window, so any kind of help would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need code for the html as well.

Comment: Hey, there! Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be nice if you could add your HTML and CSS code in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and then link it on the question so it's easier to test things out! Thanks!

Comment: you should add your HTML here...

Comment: here's the jsfiddle containing my html + css: (https://jsfiddle.net/78zd8gh5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to get you started. I don't have the HTML you use so I focused on the container.
I defined it as a flexbox which makes it responsive. Each item has a width of 33% and a height of 30px (for demo purpose).

```css
/*body stuff*/

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 80%;
}

[class^="p"] {
  width: 33%;
  height: 30px;
}

.p1 {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.p2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.p3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.p4 {
  background-color: purple;
}

.p5 {
  background-color: green;
}

.p6 {
  background-color: brown;
}

.p7 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.p8 {
  background-color: red;
}

.p9 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="p1"></div>
  <div class="p2"></div>
  <div class="p3"></div>
  <div class="p4"></div>
  <div class="p5"></div>
  <div class="p6"></div>
  <div class="p7"></div>
  <div class="p8"></div>
  <div class="p9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! instantly solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

First: I just added this CSS rule at the bottom (to overwrite the other rules) and now it works as desired:

```
 #container > div {
   width: 230px;
   margin-top: 20px;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bhzw7o60/1/

Second: For elements that have common parameters (like your floated elements which all have the same width, size and margin-top) you should use a * common*  class for all of them and additional seperate classes for the individual elements which only contain the differing properties. My above rule does this for `width` and `margin-top`. You could also add the `height` to it, and only define the `background-color` in the individual classes. BTW: `z-index` does nothing in this case, you can delete that from all the rules.